# Estimator for $\theta$ using the method of moments

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

**Exercise :**

> Using the method of moments, find the estimator for $\theta$ for a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ that follows the distribution with pdf $f(x) = \theta x^{-2}, \; 0 < \theta \leq x < \infty$, where $\theta$ is the unknown parameter.

**Attempt :**

$$m_1' = \bar{X}$$

$$μ_1' = \int_\theta^xu\theta u^{-2}\mathrm{d}u=\int_\theta^x\theta u^{-1}\mathrm{d}u=\big[\theta \ln u\big]_\theta^x =\theta\ln x - \theta\ln\theta$$

Thus, the estimator is given by :

$$m_1' = μ_1' \Rightarrow \theta\ln x - \theta\ln\theta = \bar{X}$$

But we cannot solve that equation with respect to $\theta$, so we'll take the moments of bigger order :

$$m_2' = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$$
$$μ_2' = \int_\theta^x u^2 \theta u^{-2} \mathrm{d}u = \int_\theta^x \theta \mathrm{d}u = \big[\theta u\big]_\theta^x =\theta x - \theta ^2 $$

Thus the solution of the following quadratic equation for $\theta >0$, gives as the estimator of $\theta$ :

$$\theta^2-x\theta +\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$$

**Question :** Is my solution correct ? Shall the upper bound be $x$ or $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upper bound must be $\infty$. That is a real problem since we have :

$$\int_{\theta}^A xf(x)dx\underset{A\to \infty}\to \infty.$$

Then every moment of order greater than $1$ does not exists.
One way to estimate $\theta$ is to proceed as follows :

$$E(1/X)=\int_\theta^{\infty}  \theta x^{-3} dx=\frac 1 {2 \theta}.$$

Since, by LLN :

$$\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {X_i} \to E(1/X)=\frac1{2 \theta}.$$

We deduce :

$$\frac 2 n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {X_i} \to \frac 1 \theta.$$